# Org src code block exporting even with :exports none

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

As in the title, If I have an org file with a python source block of the form

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results none :session py-sess :exports none 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print("Foo")
#+END_SRC
```

and doing `C-c C-e l o` produces a `.pdf` file with the code block exported, despite the `:exports none` header.

Adding `:eval never-export` does not help solve this.

The only way I can get around this is if I have a section heading with `:noexport` as the tag, but this is not what I want to do in my document structure, as I want to have an org file with python code blocks producing plots which I export to the `.pdf`.

As well as this, exporting this block via LaTeX to `.pdf`

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results file :session py-sess :exports results
...
filename="foo.png"
plt.save(filename)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
file:foo.png
```

produces both the figure and the code block.

How can I stop the code blocks from being exported? Is there some hidden setting I'm missing in `org-babel`?

**EDIT**
Found the problem -- had another package (`ob-sagemath`) which had the line  `(setq org-export-babel-evaluate nil)` in its `use-package` config. It seems that that variable should be set as t. I guess I could have found it sooner, but at the same time having that variable be t is a little counter-intuitive in preventing code from being exported.

Also, it took a while to figure this out as there was some weird issue in that a Python source block which printed out help(plt.savefig) caused the export process to crash (the python shell/session just got stuck), but only when running emacs in daemon/client mode and worked fine in "standalone mode". Removed that block and everything worked fine.

Comment: FWIW, I cannot reproduce this with  `Org mode version 9.5.1 (release_9.5.1-279-g8908fb)` - what version of Org mode are you using?

Comment: If there is no obvious error, i would edebug `org-babel-exp-do-export` and see what it returns and, if not the empty string, *why* it returns a a non-empty string result.

Comment: I'm using `Org mode version 9.4.4 (release_9.4.4 @ /usr/share/emacs/27.2/lisp/org/)`

Comment: You should also try with `emacs -q`, if only to eliminate the possibility that your init file is doing things it shouldn't be doing.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with Org mode version 9.4.4 either.

Comment: @NickD Thanks - it all seems to work with `emacs -q`, so it is something in my `init.el`. The only relevant lines seem to be:                                                          `(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil) ;; 
(org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages
        '((emacs-lisp . t)      (shell . t)        (latex . t)      (python . t)))`

Comment: @NickD Could you explain how to edebu `org-babel-exp-do-export`? I did `C-u C-M-x` on the function definition in the `ob-exp.el.gz`, but can't figure out where to see the results of the export from `C-c C-e l o`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132632/discussion-between-nickd-and-nonreligious).